# Program segfaults for any random double array with a size greater than 4

Tags: c, multithreading, sorting

This program takes an integer from input and populates a double array with random values and creates threads to sort each half of the array, one thread to sort the entire array, one to sort the first half, and one to sort the second half but segfaults at pthread_create(&tid1, NULL, selectionSortFirstHalf, A_First_Half). I added multiple print statements as shown below and also used gdb to confirm where the seg fault is but I'm completely lost as to why it doesn't work for array sizes greater than 4.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <pthread.h>

typedef struct merge
{
    double *FirstHalf;
    double *SecondHalf;
    double *myVal;
} MergeArray;

// Global Vars
int ArraySize;
int ArrayHalfSize;

void *mergeThread(void *args) 
{ 
    int i, j;
    MergeArray *myMerge = (struct merge *)args;

    for(i = 0; i < ArrayHalfSize; i++) 
    { 
        myMerge->myVal[i] = myMerge->FirstHalf[i];
    }
    ArraySize = ArrayHalfSize + ArrayHalfSize;

    for(i = 0, j = ArrayHalfSize; j < ArraySize && i < ArrayHalfSize; i++, j++) 
    { 
        myMerge->myVal[j] = myMerge->SecondHalf[i];
    }
    return NULL;
}

void *selectionSortThreadB(void *args) 
{ 
    double *arr; 
    double *ptrArr;
    arr = (double*)args;
    ptrArr = (double*)malloc(ArraySize * sizeof(double));
    int i;
    int j; 
    double temp;

    for(i = 1; i < ArraySize; i++) 
    { 
        temp = arr[i];
        j = i - 1;
        while(j >= 0 && arr[j] > temp) 
        { 
            arr[j + 1] = arr[j]; 
            j = j - 1;
        } 
        arr[j + 1] = temp;
    } 
    /*for(i = 0; i < ArraySize; i++) 
    { 
        printf("SSTB: %d, %.2lf\n", i, arr[i]);
    }*/
    ptrArr = arr;
    pthread_exit((void*)ptrArr);
}

void *selectionSortSecondHalf(void *args) 
{ 
    double *myarr, *myptrretSecondHalf; 
    myarr = (double *)args; 
    myptrretSecondHalf = (double *)malloc(ArrayHalfSize * sizeof(double)); 
    
    if(myptrretSecondHalf == NULL) 
    { 
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not allocate memory in selectionSortSecondtHalf\n"); 
        exit(-1); 
    } 
    int i, j; 
    int min; 
    double temp; 

    /*for(i = ArrayHalfSize; i < ArraySize; i++) 
    { 
        printf("This is the second half of the array when passed to SSSH: A_Second_Half[%d] = %.2lf\n", i, myarr[i]);
    }*/
    
    for (i = ArrayHalfSize; i < ArraySize; i++) 
    { 
        min = i; 
        for(j = i + 1; j < ArraySize; j++) 
        { 
            if(myarr[j] < myarr[min]) 
             min = j; 
        } 
        temp = myarr[i]; 
        myarr[i] = myarr[min]; 
        myarr[min] = temp; 
    }
    myptrretSecondHalf = myarr;
    pthread_exit(myptrretSecondHalf);
}


void *selectionSortFirstHalf(void *args) 
{ 
    //printf("hello from 104\n");
    double *myarr, *myptrretFirstHalf; 
    myarr = (double *)args; 
    myptrretFirstHalf = (double *)malloc(ArrayHalfSize * sizeof(double)); 
    
    if(myptrretFirstHalf == NULL) 
    { 
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not allocate memory in selectionSortFirstHalf\n"); 
        exit(-1); 
    } 
    int i, j; 
    int min; 
    double temp; 

    /*for(i = 0; i < ArrayHalfSize; i++) 
    { 
        printf("This is the first half of the array when passed to SSFH: A_First_Half[%d] = %.2lf\n", i, myarr[i]);
    }*/
    
    for (i = 0; i < ArrayHalfSize; i++) 
    { 
        min = i; 
        for(j = i + 1; j < ArrayHalfSize; j++) 
        { 
            if(myarr[j] < myarr[min]) 
             min = j; 
        } 
        temp = myarr[i]; 
        myarr[i] = myarr[min]; 
        myarr[min] = temp; 
    }
    myptrretFirstHalf = myarr; 
    pthread_exit(myptrretFirstHalf); 
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{ 
    if(argc != 2) 
    { 
        fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: Please provide the correct number of arguments (file, size of array)\n");
        exit(-1);
    }
    else
    { 
        ArraySize = atoi(argv[1]);
        ArrayHalfSize = (ArraySize / 2);
        clock_t start, end, start2, end2;
        double RandomNum; 
        double *ThreadBlock; 
        double *ThreadArrayHalf1; 
        double *ThreadArrayHalf2; 
        pthread_t tid, tid1, tid2, tid3; 
        double A[ArraySize]; 
        double B[ArraySize]; 
        //double C[ArraySize]; 
        double *A_First_Half/*[ArrayHalfSize]*/; 
        double *A_Second_Half/*[ArrayHalfSize]*/;
        A_First_Half = (double*)malloc(sizeof(A_First_Half)*ArrayHalfSize);
        A_Second_Half = (double*)malloc(sizeof(A_Second_Half)*ArrayHalfSize);
        int i;

        srand(time(NULL)); // generate seed for rand nums based on time

        for(i = 0; i < ArraySize; i++) 
        { 
            RandomNum = ((double) rand()*(1000.0+1.0)/(double)RAND_MAX+1.0);
            printf("%.2lf\n", RandomNum);
            A[i] = RandomNum;
        }
        for(i = 0; i < ArraySize; i++) 
        { 
            B[i] = A[i];
        }
        start = clock();
        pthread_create(&tid, NULL, selectionSortThreadB, (void*)B);
        pthread_join(tid, (void**)&ThreadBlock);
        end = clock() - start;
        printf("Sorting is done in %.2fms when one thread is used\n", end * 1000.0 / CLOCKS_PER_SEC); 
        
//*******Two-Threaded Option**************//
        // prints A[]
        for(i = 0; i < ArraySize; i++) 
        { 
            printf("A[%d] = %.2lf\n", i, A[i]);
        }
        // populates first half of array A with half of A
        for(i = 0; i < ArrayHalfSize; i++) 
        { 
            A_First_Half[i] = A[i];
            printf("A_First_Half[%d] = %.2lf\n", i, A_First_Half[i]);
        }
        // populates second half of array A with second half of B
        for(i = ArrayHalfSize; i < ArraySize; i++) 
        { 
            A_Second_Half[i] = A[i]; 
            printf("A_Second_Half[%d] = %.2lf\n", i, A_Second_Half[i]);
        }

        printf("hello from 199\n");  
        start2 = clock();
        printf("hello from 201\n");
        pthread_create(&tid1, NULL, selectionSortFirstHalf, A_First_Half);
        printf("hello from 203\n");
        pthread_create(&tid2, NULL, selectionSortSecondHalf, A_Second_Half);
        printf("hello from 205\n");
        pthread_join(tid1, (void**)&ThreadArrayHalf1); 
        pthread_join(tid2, (void**)&ThreadArrayHalf2);
        MergeArray threadMerge; 
        threadMerge.myVal = (double*)malloc(ArraySize * sizeof(double));
        for(i = 0; i < ArrayHalfSize; i++) 
        { 
            printf("SSFH: %d, %.2lf\n", i, ThreadArrayHalf1[i]); 
        }
        for(i = ArrayHalfSize; i < ArraySize; i++) 
        { 
            printf("SSSH: %d, %.2lf\n", i, ThreadArrayHalf2[i]); 
        } 
        threadMerge.FirstHalf = ThreadArrayHalf1; 
        threadMerge.SecondHalf = ThreadArrayHalf2; 
        pthread_create(&tid3, NULL, mergeThread, (void*)&threadMerge); 
        pthread_join(tid3, NULL);
        end2 = clock() - start2;  
        printf("Sorting is done in %.2fms when two threads are used\n", end2 * 1000.0 / CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
        //free(A_First_Half);
        //free(A_Second_Half);
        //free(threadMerge.myVal);
    } 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: All your threads access and modify `ArraySize` and `ArrayHalfSize` without any synchronization or locking.  That doesn't seem good.

Comment: Re “// populates second half of array A with second half of B”: No, that is not what that loop is doing.

Comment: The second argument to `pthread_join` should be a pointer to a `void *`, not the address of some other pointer that has been cast to `void **`. Accept it as a `void *` and **after** the `pthread_join`, convert it to the type you need. E.g., to receive a `MergeArray` from a thread, use `void *temp; pthread_join(foo, &temp); MergeArray *p = temp;`.

Answer (score 0):

`A_First_Half = (double*)malloc(sizeof(A_First_Half)*ArrayHalfSize);` allocates space based on `sizeof(A_First_Half)`, which uses the size of the pointer `A_First_Half`, not the size of the object it points to, `*A_First_Half`.

And you do not need the parentheses for `sizeof` with an expression or the cast of malloc. So use `A_First_Half = malloc(sizeof *A_First_Half * ArrayHalfSize);`.

In several places, a “second half” array is used with indices running from `ArrayHalfSize` to `ArraySize-1`. However, they point to storage for which space for `ArrayHalfSize` elements has been allocated. Indices in that space run from 0 to `ArrayHalfSize-1`. All the code should be changed to use only indices from 0 to `ArrayHalfSize-1` with these “second halves.”

Along those lines, there is no need for `selectionSortFirstHalf` and `selectionSortSecondHalf` to be separate routines. Once `selectionSortSecondHalf` is fixed, per above, it will do the same thing as `selectionSortFirstHalf`: Sort an array with `ArrayHalfSize` elements.

Once you have fixed those and gotten the program working, eliminate the global variables and pass all the necessary information to the threads via their argument pointer (by pointing to a structure that contains the information the thread needs).